# Luxor Pool API (Create subaccount, delete subaccount)

Tags: python, django, backend

**Question:**
when create a subaccount on luxor pool it create the user but when I delete the same user by calling delete subaccount API. It does not give me access to create the same user subaccount with the same name.

**Error:**

> {"errors":[{"message":"error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_username_key"","locations":[{"line":3,"column":9}],"path":["provisionNewUser"]}],"data":{"provisionNewUser":null}}

**Subaccounts list:**

```
{
"success": true,
"message": "",
"data": {
    "users": {
        "edges": [
            {
                "node": {
                    "username": "cxdevs"
                }
            },
            {
                "node": {
                    "username": "user-1"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Note: I have delete the account with the same name when I first created it. And after deleting it does give me access to create with the same name. (Luxor Pool APIs)